# AppleScript to take text and turn it into pasteable HTML

Tags: macos, replace, applescript, clipboard

We work with bugzilla.  Whenever you need to query a ticket you just need to know the bugid (integer) and you simply prepend this to it.

```
http://<bugzilla_server>/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=<bug_id>
```

Suppose I have a bug link which looks like this [777](http://bugzilla_server/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=bug_id).  If I select and copy this it is preserved on the pasteboard so when I paste this into mail it will correctly preserve the link and it's attributes.

What I am looking for is to simple type '777' select it and run an applescript on it and replace it with a link like the one above.  Can anyone help me out??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following AppleScript will take the contents of the clipboard and replace it with the URL prepended:

```
set the clipboard to "http://bugzilla_server/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=" & (the clipboard)
```

You can compile that to an AppleScript `scpt` and make it available in a `Scripts` folder or compile it to a launchable `app`:

```
osacompile -e 'set the clipboard to "http://bugzilla_server/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=" & (the clipboard)' -o replacebug.scpt  # or -o replacebug.app
```

If your primary use case for this is in composing mail in `Mail.app`, this may not be the most user-friendly approach, though.  If you are using Snow Leopard (10.6), a simpler solution is to take advantage of the new `Text Substitution` feature.  Open the `System Preferences -> Language & Text` preference panel, select the `Text` tab, and click `+` to add a new substitution, perhaps:

```
Replace   With

  (b)     http://bugzilla_server/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=
```

Then, in `Mail.app`, start a `New Message` and, with the cursor clicked within the text body, do a Control click of the mouse to bring up the contextual menu.  From it, select `Substitutions -> Text Replacement`.  From now on, as you are typing in the text body of the email when you type:

```
(b)777
```

the `(b)` will automatically change to the URL text you saved:

```
http://bugzilla_server/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=777
```

This will also work in other Cocoa text-enabled applications like Safari.

EDIT:

When talking about composing URL links in email, there are at least three different formats of email, each with a different solution.  Since you don't say which kind you are using, I'll cover all three:

1. Plain text format - There's no way to "hide" the URL in the composed email although some email readers might present a clickable link for a plain-text URL.
2. HTML-formatted email - Apple's `Mail.app` does not support composing email in this format although it will display it.  Using some other mail writer client or your own program, it's easy enough to compose a link using a standard HTML anchor `<a href=...>` tag.
3. Rich Text Format email - AFAIK, this is the only way to compose a URL link with `Mail.app`.  Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an easy way to directly create an RTF hyperlink using AppleScript commands.  Based on a suggestion [here](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/04/14/speedy-creation-of-rich-text-links-to-mail-messages/), this is a way to do it by creating a modifiable RTF template via the clipboard.

   - In `TextEdit.app`, create a new Document window.
   - Insert the text you want to appear in the email, i.e. `777`.
   - Select the text (⌘A) then add a link (⌘K). Enter the full URL also with `777` into the "Link destination" field; click OK.
   - Modify the text format as desired with Format menu commands.
   - Save the file (⇧⌘S) as `temp.rtf` with `File Format` -> `Rich Text Format`.
   - Close the document window.
   - Open a document window (⌘O) selecting file `temp.rtf` and selecting `Ignore rich text commands`.
   - Insert the following before the first line in the file:

     ```
     #!/bin/sh
     sed -e "s/777/$(pbpaste -Prefer txt)/g" <<EOF | pbcopy -Prefer rtf
     ```
   - Append `EOF` as a separate line at the end of the file.

     It should now look something like this:

     ```
     #!/bin/sh
     sed -e "s/777/$(pbpaste -Prefer txt)/g" <<EOF | pbcopy -Prefer rtf
     {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf250
     {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
     {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
     \margl1440\margr1440\vieww9000\viewh8400\viewkind0
     \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural
     {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "http://bugzilla_server/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=777"}}{\fldrslt 
     \f0\fs24 \cf0 777}}}
     EOF
     ```
   - Save this as a `Plain Text` file and execute directly as a shell script or call it via the AppleScript `do shell script` command.

   This kind of solution will work with most other applications that support Rich Text format.

Comment: I'll give you points for effort.  But this isn't really what I'm after as this will simply just past the 'http://stuff'.  The question I am trying to solve is how does mac understand a a html element and paste it appropriate element as a valid link.  What should be shown after the translation is simply '777' but as an html link element.

Comment: Wow!! You nailed it.  This is really powerful Thanks for taking the time to solve this one!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly the function you're looking for, but this will take a number from your clipboard and process it into a link and put the link on the clipboard as a standard href URL that will work in plain or rich text, like:
`<a href="http://<bugzilla_server>/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=777" title="777">Bug number 777 link</a>`

Change `<bugzilla_server>` to your working URL.

```
set bug_number to the clipboard

set the_text to "<a href=\"http://<bugzilla_server>/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=" & bug_number & "\" title=\"" & bug_number & "\">Bug number " & bug_number & " link</a>"

set the clipboard to the_text
```

Comment: Are you sure that actually works in Apple's Rich Text Format email? That works for HTML-enabled email as I noted in my reply; standard RTF doesn't directly use HTML tags, AFAIK.

Comment: My point is not that it may or may not work in RTF or HTML email; I'm focusing on his original question: "What I am looking for is to simple type '777' select it and run an applescript on it and replace it with a link like the one above."